# Vagrant VirtualBox error when installing service fabric cluster on OSX

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, azure-service-fabric, vagrantfile

[Service Fabric Cluster Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTnAO.png)

Hi, I am trying to get an application run on my MacOS system which requires service fabric cluster. I tried to install it via this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-mac.md). However, I came across this error when trying to `vagrant up`. I have already spent half a day trying to solve this through many resources and failed.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: `VERRDISKFULL` most likely you do not have enough free space on your drive to create the VM

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Thanks! After a long day, all I had to do was delete those game of thrones episodes lol.